# Windows command line - for error: %pid was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I am trying to kill a Hybris server process through command line. When the server is started, it writes the process ID (PID) to a file. I want to read that PID and then kill it. I am giving the below command for this but everytime I get:

> ```
> %pid was unexpected at this time.
> ```

This is the command that I fired:

```
for /f %pid in (D:\path_to_hybris\hybris\data\hybristomcat.lock) do taskkill /f /pid %pid
```

Comment: Can you try to fix the line to: `for /f pid in (D:\path_to_hybris\hybris\data\hybristomcat.lock) do taskkill /f /pid %pid%`? Does it help?

Comment: On doing this, I get the below error:
`in was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: Try: `for /f %p in (D:\path_to_hybris\hybris\data\hybristomcat.lock) do taskkill /f /pid %p`. I think this should work.

Comment: Yes, that worked :)
So the problem was that pid is a reserved word

Comment: No, `pid` is not a reserved word; [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) expects a loop reference consisting of a single letter only, so `%p` is good, but `%pid` is bad. Regard that when using the `for` loop in a batch file rather than in command prompt directly, you must double the `%` sign, hence use `%%p` then! Type `for /?` into a new command prompt window to get the help text and read it carefully...

Comment: I put up an official answer for later reference by others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following syntax:

```
for /f %p in (D:\path_to_hybris\hybris\data\hybristomcat.lock) do taskkill /f /pid %p
```

If in a batch file, you need to double the `%`

```
for /f %%p in (D:\path_to_hybris\hybris\data\hybristomcat.lock) do taskkill /f /pid %%p
```

The use of a word as a loop variable causes problems. Stick to a single letter.

NOTE - as mentioned in a comment by @SomethingDark, the variable `p` is case sensitive!

I hope this helps.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that this is the only time a batch variable is case-sensitive.